Gibbs free energy change for cells at different temperatures

Why is $\Delta G=\Delta G^o+RT\ln Q?$

The standard proof states $\Delta G = V \Delta P - S\Delta T$ and T is constant so $\Delta G = V \Delta P$ . Till now I understand but after that the ideal gas law is brought and $V$ is related to $P$ . I am not able to understand the reason because the volume $V$ of the cell compartments are fixed so $\Delta G = V (P_f-P_i)$ . Can someone please justify the involvement of gas law ?

Apparently the title of the question asks about the change of Free enthalpy versus temperature for cells. This is related to a galvanic cell and to the chemical rections occurring in such a cell. But the text of the question states about a quite different problem. It considers the value of Delta G in a gas when the pressure is changed without any chemical reaction. This is something totally different.

@Maurice I also think the same . But the derivation of the opening formulla is done in that way . I just want to know how is the volume change in a cell related to gas law. Volume of every part is constant

dG=-S.dT + V.dp + sum (mu-i . dn_i) // The above analysis ignores G changes due composition changes.

What kind of cell do you mean? What do you mean by "standard proof". Can you link to this or provide a reference?

@BuckThorn suppose silver , hydrogen redox electrochemical cell

I would consider Poutnik's comments. Also, do you have access to a textbook or online notes? The equation you are starting from ($\Delta G = V\Delta p$) is not quite the standard approach. Usually you start from $dG = Vdp$. That's followed by additional assumptions such as considering the system to be a mixture of ideal gases. Finally you remove those assumptions but retain the form of the expressions and introduce tweaking factors that account for non-ideality.
